# SQL query: Show all from A that have B as C

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

```
Id  Parinte     Angajator
1   Parinte1    Firma1
2   Parinte2    Firma2
3   Parinte3    Firma3


Id  Copil   Data_Nastere    Id_Parinte  Data_creare
1   Copil1  10.01.2013      1   
2   Copil2  11.11.2012      1   
3   Copil3  10.10.2013      2   
4   Copil4  12.11.2013      2
```

I have these 2 tables (1st let's say table1 and 2nd table2)

I need to do the following operations on these 2 tables.

I need them in a query so I can copy paste it for project!

1. Show all from "Parinti" that have "Angajator" as "Firma1"
2. Show all from "Copil" that have "Parinte1"
3. Update the field "Data_creare" from table2 with current date for "Copil" that have "Parent1"
4. Delete all from "Copil" that have "Data_Naster" = 10.01.2013
5. last I need to sort the values from table2 column "Copil" ascending ascending depending of  field "Data_nastere"

Comment: Pro tip: to increase the chance of a better answer, you should not only write _"I need them in a query so I can copy paste it for project!"_ but also some motivation for us, like _"Hurry up!"_ or _"What do I pay you for?"_

Comment: Don't get me wrong, i am noob at sql, point nr. 1  i've  made it , but for the other ones, i don't know how to properly use INNER JOIN, EXIST and so on(that's why i asked for the querry). I know someone good at sql will probably solve all of them in under 5 mins, but since i am a noob , i am afraid i will mess up.

Comment: I have this ideea for no.2 but i don't know how to continue further        SELECT *
FROM tabel1
INNER JOIN tabel2
ON tabel1.Id = tabel2.Id_Parinte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least you have to type it yourself!

[image: Statements]

Comment: Ty, you are a life savior !  /bow/